# Inequations on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f : \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ an holomorphic function such as

$$\exists C_0 > 0 / \forall z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \qquad |f(z)| \leqslant C_0\left( |z| + \frac{1}{|z|}\right)$$

I have to show that there exists $C >0$ such as

$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \qquad |f'(z)| \leqslant C_0\left( 1 + \frac{1}{|z|^2}\right)$$

---

What I have tried :

We know that, if we call $D$ the circle of center $z$ and radius $r \leqslant |z|$, we have

$$|f'(z)| \leqslant \frac{1}{r} \sup_{\partial D} |f|$$

where $\partial D = \{ u \in \mathbb{C} / |u-z| = r \}$.

My idea was to have a nicer inequality and then doing $r \to |z|$.
So, if $u\in \partial D$, we have $u = z + r e^{it}$ so clearly $$|z| - r \leqslant |u| \leqslant |z| + r$$

So that $$|f(u)| \leqslant C_0\left( |u| + \frac{1}{|u|}\right) \leqslant C_0\left( |z| + r + \frac{1}{|z| - r}\right)$$

which does not depend of $u$, so I can take the $\sup$ of that. The thing is that I'll have some trouble when I'll try to do $r \to |z|$.

So I'm kind of lost and I would like a little hint as to get closer to the answer.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Using the original condition $zf(z)$ is bounded near the origin, so $f$ has a simple pole at most at the origin.
- A similar reasoning gives that $f(z)$ has at most a simple pole at infinity.
- $f$ is thus a rational function (being meromorphic in $\overline{\mathbb{C}})$.

Justification for the third: $zf(z)$ is an entire function, with a pole (of degree $\leq 2$) at infinity. The Taylor expansion $zf(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ must then reduce to a polynomial (otherwise there will be an essential singularity at $\infty$).

Comment: It does not seems obvious to me that the third point follows from the first and the second. Can you please give me a very quick proof so as to convince me ?
I'll try to get it from there. Thanks !